# SFTP file transfer in Windows using script with no external dependency

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, sftp

I need to know can we transfer file through SFTP using script.

I am able to ping server from my system but when I use `ftp` command it shows *"connection lost"* and when I use `sftp` command it shows *"command does not exist"*.

No external PuTTY or WinSCP can be used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Only recent versions of Windows 10 come with Win32-OpenSSH build of OpenSSH tools built in.

In older versions, there's no SFTP support in Windows built-in commands, PowerShell, .NET framework or any other scripting language (like WSH/JScript/VBScript) readily available. On these versions you have to use an external software or a library.

- you can install [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH), or
- for solutions in PowerShell, see:
  [Upload file to SFTP using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38732025/850848)
- for solutions in batch file, see:
  [Secure FTP using Windows batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16150152/850848)